# How to read QTDataStream structure in Python?

Tags: python, qt

I have a package received from UDP socket (bytes) and I know it is a QTDataStream structure, also I have a header file for this structure, but I can't find any way to get a Python object from this package. Is there any module for Python or some way to solve this problem?

Here is a package that I receive:

```
b'0\x00\x00\x00\x00c\xdaHP\x00\x00\x01j\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00S\x00e\x00e\x00k\x00e\x00r\x00_\x000\x000\x000\x003\x006\x002BP\x00\x00BT\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x7f\xff\xff\xff\xff\x18\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\xfc\x06Av\x13\x00\x00\x7f\xd4\x18\x98\x95\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\xfc\x06Aw\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I have no idea what to do in order to get information from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ctypes.  This will let you replicate a C structure definition and pick apart the data, for example:

```
from ctypes import *
class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", c_int),
                ("y", c_int)]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Without knowing your structure definition I can't really go further than that, but the docs explain the primitive types and how to put together struct and union definitions.

From that you can pass in the data with `from_buffer`.  This should allow you to poke about the data you've gotten from the network request.